# Cannot assign a tuple to a variable 'macd'

Tags: pine-script

Here is my code in tradingview:

```
// Inputs
rsi_length = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
rsi_overbought = input.int(70, "RSI Overbought Level", minval=1, maxval=100)
rsi_oversold = input.int(30, "RSI Oversold Level", minval=1, maxval=100)
macd_fast = input.int(12, "MACD Fast Length", minval=1)
macd_slow = input.int(26, "MACD Slow Length", minval=1)
macd_signal = input.int(9, "MACD Signal Length", minval=1)

// Indicators
rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)
macd = (ta.macd(close, macd_fast, macd_slow, macd_signal))
```

And the error i get:
Invalid assignment. Cannot assign a tuple to a variable 'macd'.

i have asked binggpt but it says the code must work.

Answer (score 0):

`ta.macd` returns a tuple, therefore you need to use a tuple instead of a variable with it.

```
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, macd_fast, macd_slow, macd_signal)
plot(macdLine, color=color.blue)
plot(signalLine, color=color.orange)
plot(histLine, color=color.red, style=plot.style_histogram)
```